Does deserialize method(mapper.readValue) allocate direct buffer memory instead of heap memory?
I would like to ask you something about ObjectMapper.readvalue().
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

List<ConvertType> responseList = new ArrayList<>();
for (ExampleContent content : iterable) {
    String json = new String(content.getData(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    responseList.add(mapper.readValue(json, ConvertType));

Like the code above, I want to deserialize and save the json data to the list.
However, when I execute the code repeatedly, the direct buffer memory usage increases. Sometimes, Out of direct buffer memory problem occurs.
Does deserializing using ObjectMapper allocates direct buffer memory rather than heap memory?
If so, How can I reduce the amount of direct buffer memory used?

It’s rather unlikely that the deserialization uses a buffer at all when the input is already a String. The critical operation in this example is the content.getData() which, as far as we can see, is responsible for fetching data from somewhere and returning as a byte array (as we can deduce from the String constructor).

The ObjectMapper uses heap memory for deserialization, not direct buffer memory. Direct memory is primarily used for IO operations.
I suggest using profiling tools to identify the source that causes the direct memory buffer to increase which may stem from memory leaks elsewhere in the application. Additionally, ensure that a single instance of ObjectMapper is used to reduce the overheard of creating new instances.
